# Passive Filter Negative Insertion Loss

Tags: rf, filter, design

Can someone please explain to me how a passive filter could possibly have a negative insertion loss? In the attached picture, this can be seen in the C or D curves where the insertion loss dips below 0 dB. I understand the filter is resonant at this frequency, but I don't understand how resonance could lead to a negative insertion loss on a passive circuit.  This seems to conflict with the fact that passive circuits can't generate power.

[image: Filter Insertion Loss]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passive circuits cannot produce a power gain but they can produce a voltage gain.  A resonant circuit can produce a voltage gain equal to its Q. If the impedance levels are considered, there is no power gain.

Comment: Thanks Barry!  I didn't realize it was voltage ratio.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice [white paper](http://schaffner.com/tw/downloads/file-download/file/cispr-17-measurements.pdf) from SCHAFFNER explaining the 0.1/100 Ohm curves.

Note that attenuation is measured as a voltage ratio (not a power ratio), so when working at different input/output impedances, you can actually have a voltage gain.

Comment: Ah, the clarity...I didn't realize it was a voltage ratio and not power ratio!  I knew I was missing something.  Thanks for the response!